# How to bind a URL parameter with an input field in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, url-parameters

I have an example running [here](https://0t7ex6qjcf.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/staging/?amount=123), where the input is set by `?amount=123`

```js
const query = new URL(location).searchParams
const amount = parseFloat(query.get('amount'))

console.log("amount", amount)
document.getElementById('amount').value = amount
```

```html
<label>
  Amount
  <input id="amount" type="number" name="amount">
</label>
```

Sorry, running the code snippet above or on JS fiddle doesn't appear to work with URL parameters.

If the input is changed, I **want the URL to update too**, with the new value. How do I achieve that in vanilla JS?

Comment: you can  simply use history API to change the URL

Comment: do you need it to reload the page too or just add it to the URL address and history or just alter the URL address without adding it to the history?

Comment: Is this your jsfiddle?  https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/e67ywq8f/?amount=231

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add an `input` event listener and use `window.history.replaceState`:

```
const origin = window.location.origin;
const path = window.location.pathname;

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    // Set the new 'amount' value
    query.set('amount', input.value);
    // Replace the history entry
    window.history.replaceState(
        null,
        '',
        origin + path + '?amount=' + query.get('amount')
    );
});
```

Comment: Building the url by concatenating strings like this: `origin + path + '?amount=' + query.get('amount')` ... is this best practice?

Comment: It only alters the `amount` query and maintains the original URL, so, I'd say so.

Comment: Using full (absolute) URL might be reasonable precaution for untested browsers, but from what I've tried using just the (relative) `'?search'` fragment instead works the same. (Looking at specs I think it should work this way, because base should be the implied from `window.location`, but I'm not sure I understand it correctly; https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-history-replacestate )